# Error while connecting to remote Postgres on centos

Tags: postgresql, azure, centos

When I'm trying to connect to Postgres on remote cloud . It is showing :

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
      This probably means the server terminated abnormally
      before or while processing the request.
```

Local system -- Postgres 9.3 (windows)
Remote System is on Azure -- Postgres 9.2(centos)

Command I'm using: `psql -h "abc.cloudapp.net" -p 5432`

I've set the end-point as 5432 in azure 
changed the postgresql.conf to "*" to allow connection 
and changed the pg_hba to `(host all all ip/24 md5)`

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint is OK, and you need to set up the network security group as well.

[image]

Try to define not just 5432, but the range of ports (1024-65536 for example).

**UPD**: I was able to create the CentOs 7.0 + PostgreSQL and connected to that instance:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contribs
sudo postgresql-setup initdb
sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Edit 127.0.0.1/32 to 0.0.0.0/0

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
sudo systemctl enable postgresql    
sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
sudo service postgresql restart   
sudo service postgresql restart   
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser azureuser -P
```

Then i downloaded [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org) and connected to that. (see screenshot) (do not pay attention to the test1 database, just change it to postgres).

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this in azure classic portal . Please share the screenshot .

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Did you create your VM on the classic portal, right?

Comment: Yes I did create but in newer Portal I dont have network security group

Comment: Ok, you do not have the reputation to go to the chat :( Let's try to do it here. You configured 5432 port and any settings inside of the VM?

Comment: I dont have reputation

Comment: Ok. So, everything is as described here?  Did you restart the psql? http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/setting-up-postgresql-in-azure-vm/

Comment: Good. May you go to SSH and run netstat -tunlp | grep 5432 ? What it shows?

Comment: tcp        0      0 100.92.2.49:16001       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      880/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3802/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2035/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      880/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      3802/postgres

Comment: @PrabalDas i managed to make it working. Please see the answer